# I want make bar chart, hel me

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, bar-chart

#### I have output like this..

> {"belum":48,"proses":64,"selesai":104}

I want make to chart, how to make that into bar chart? please help me, im beginner.. thanks

Comment: There are several tutorials linked from google, if you search

Answer (score 3):

This is done by a magical thing called JSON(Javascript Object Notation).
Since you are a beginner, I'm not going to give a wall of code where you won't understand. So the steps are below:

You will have to choose a chart that you like, whether google or another chartmaker.

and this will allow guide you on the basics on it,
https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/creating-charts-using-json/

This will help you on it in code form :
    http://jsfiddle.net/gwC2V/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries you can use for free. Personally I like to use [MorrisJS](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/).

Check the home page tutorial, it's so simple to use the json data to create charts.